# Entity Data Model Designer - case sensitive on property names

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ado.net-entity-data-model

I was creating my entity on the Entity Data Model Designer and by mistake I created 2 properties with the same name but different cases, lets say `CustomerID` and `CustomerId`.

Since the Entity Data Model Designer is case sensitive, it didn't complain and generated the script, but when executing it, it failed because I ended up having a table with 2 columns with the same name.

My question is, is there a way of making the Entity Data Model Designer case-insensitive, so it can see that `CustomerID` and `CustomerId` are the same column and I can spot these errors during development?

Comment: I don't know of a way - maybe something to suggest for future versions- but not that huge of a deal really as it does get caught the moment we go to run the SQL and it's not as though we spend a huge amount of time with Entity Designer in terms of the project timescale. Assuming there isn't an "Option Strict", if it became a serious question one could write a little tool to scan the XML of the EDMX file and pick up equivalent entity names, but I suspect writing the tool would take longer than ignoring the problem and fixing any collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this validation option is not part of Entity Data Model Designer. EDMX and C# are case sensitive and even SQL Server can be case sensitive if you set up your database that way.